# Importing online CSV Feed into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, wsdl, feed

We have a web feed CSV file on our company's website and I would like to be able to import into it on a daily basis. I can certainly save it as a .txt file and import it, however, I would prefer to have it connected to my SQL Server database and import directly into it without having to download it to a .txt file first.

I have SQL Server Integrated Services but am not sure which method to use. So far it looks like creating a Web Service is the best route but I am unfamiliar with creating a WSDL file. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are using an app language like C# or Java, then you could handle this from there.

Comment: I am using c# in Visual Studio.  I am attempting to try to build an application for our pricing of motorcycles and I need the data from the CSV feed to let me know which units we have listed on the website and if we have the current prices on them.  We currently have 7 pages of prices to keep track of.

I was wondering what options there are within a c# app.  I see two different options on APIs but I am not sure which one would do the job.